# Node js http server accept POST and accept JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to create one Node js server with http package. I want to receive only POST request which I have already implemented it. The problem which I am facing is that I am not able to parse JSON correctly (I am expecting one JSON to be attached).

I tried using JSON.parse but that doesn't parse whole json content. It leaves some values as [Object] which is wrong. I saw few packages which is JSONStream but I am not sure how to implement in this case.

```
server.on('request', function(req, res){
    if(req.method == 'POST')
    {
        var jsonString;

        req.on('data', function (data) {
            jsonString = JSON.parse(data);
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            serverNext(req, res, jsonString);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        res.writeHead(405, {'Content-type':'application/json'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify({error: "Method not allowed"}, 0, 4));
    }       
    res.end();
});
```

Request example:

Here d = JSON file content. (I did this in Python to make this example request)

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9001', headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}, data = json.dumps(d))
```

Note: I am able to parse JSON correctly but there are some cases when it shows something like this:

```
{ 'Heading': 
   { 'Content': 
      { sometext: 'value',
        List: [Object],         // Wrong
        test: [Array] } } }     // Wrong
```

Update:

Inside serverNext() I am getting few values like:

```
var testReq = Object.keys(jsonData)[0];
var testId = Object.keys(jsonData[testRequest])[0];
var test = jsonData[testRequest][testId]
```

Further if I keep on extracting values then at some point it encounters [Objects] value and get crashed.

Comment: what is the `jsonString` like you want to parse

Comment: Just a variable to pass it to another function. data is the thing which I need to parse from POST method.

Comment: what is your data

Comment: data is the JSON content. It will be like { "Foo": {"Bar": {"Some data": [list]} } } where list is showing as [Object] or any other nested object. I just want to parse whole content

Comment: @ShashankSharma Can you provide the body of the HTTP POST request?

Comment: @shaochuancs I just updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this "problem" with `data` as `{ "Foo": {"Bar": {"Some data": [43, 32, 44]} } }` -- it returns the following result: `{ Foo: { Bar: { 'Some data': [Object] } } }`.

As OP mentioned in question, the JSON is parsed correctly, the reason why `[Object]` is displayed in result is: when JavaScript Object is returned to display, it would be converted to String first by `toString()` automatically, which will make all object (including array) as `[Object]` in text.

To display the real content, `JSON.stringify()` need to be invoked. In your case, the code would be:

```
req.on('end', function () {
    serverNext(req, res, JSON.stringify(jsonString));
});
```

Please note it is better to rename variable `jsonString` as `jsonObject`.

Comment: I tried this too but in later operation like inside serverNext() function I won't be able to get values from json like extracting key value (I tried). So again I might need to parse it. That's what I observed. For example if I extract keys from that stringify JSON then I will get ['0', '1', '2' .... till 20,000 times]

Comment: Ah, then it is OK to parse `jsonString` as it is, and use `JSON.stringify()` inside `serverNext()` function, when it is finally returned to client.

Comment: But then if I parse that string again, then it again become the same problem right ? But are you suggesting me to first stringify the nested JSON like which is showing [Objects] and then again parse it ?

Comment: @ShashankSharma If `serverNext()` function can be included in this question, I'd be glad to provide the example code.

Comment: @ShashankSharma No, I'm suggesting using `JSON.stringify()` only before the result is sent to user. There is no need to parse-stringify-parse..., that would be inefficient.

Comment: I updated my question as if I what I am doing inside that function

Comment: @ShashankSharma Can you provide the code that "it encounters [Objects] value and get crashed"?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. For some reason that stringify method works fine. I implemented the same thing. I just split the JSON content into various part and then I fixed it.